# What do you call this in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality

I'm looking for/seeking a word that is the opposite of "hospitable".
I don't mean inhospitable. I'm going to talk about a society that praises strangers, and I'd like to be natural.
Let me know if there's anything wrong with my writing, grammatically or otherwise.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109000/discussion-on-question-by-navid-tavakoli-what-do-you-call-this-in-english).